# How should I handle routing with nested Module in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to handle routing with nested modules in Angular in best way.

Let's say that I start application with URL localhost:5000. I should see `HomeComponent` with some content on left side and on the right side I have `<router-outlet>` where should be rendered `ContactComponent`. If I will go to localhost:5000/info then `ContactComponent` should be replaced by `InfoComponent`. How Can I achive this?

This is what I have so far:
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-jb9y3u?file=src/app/home/home-routing.module.ts

(`ContactComponent` is not rendering and if I go to localhost:5000/info then `InfoComponent` will render in `<router-outlet>` from `AppComponent`

And image for better explanation:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some problems with your routes. 
You should learn more about using the children's property of route.

Also, pay attention to the pathMatch

link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-rfeaup

Answering the comment, yes I was added lazy-loading. Otherwise, I can't see what is the sense to use the featured module. The lazy module is a functional module that separates a part of application functionality. If you are using lazy-modules, it's somewhat better for the client because the client shouldn't wait for all the app loaded, but the core.

More about lazy-loading in the Angular application: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Well, and about "Children" - "contains all the child routes activated under the current route" - according to the official documentation.

I believe you can find it helpful as well: https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration

Comment: Nice, this is almost a good answer. But perhaps, you want to explain that you've added lazy loading (and what is it), and also briefly explain how children property works or perhaps a link to the official docs? Welcome to SO, anyway! =)

Comment: If I would not to use lazy loading how the AppModule would looks like? instead `loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule',`

Comment: you'd import the HomeModule into AppModule. And append the following in the app-routing, under HomeComponent path:     children: [
      {
        path: '', component: ContactComponent
      }
    ]
Rewrite from loadChildren to 'path: '', component: HomeComponent'

Comment: So actually as @Andreas Högbom answered. Right?

Comment: Yeap, but don't forget to import HomeModule into AppModule.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in app-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: ContactComponent,
      },
      {
        path: "info",
        component: InfoComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: This works. The empty top route for the HomeComponent has no purpose though as this will always match.

Answer (score 0):

You now have no purpose for the top level router-outlet (in AppComponent). If it would have a purpose (to match the HomeComponent on say '/home') then you could have matched a second route in the second router-outlet with some children of the 'home' route (ContactComponent => '/home/contact' and InfoComponent => '/home/info').